# Why do I have an orange line in my Github 'Open pull request' page?

Tags: github, pull-request, git-diff

I have an orange line in my Github 'Open pull request' page. The file itself is a rake file and the line(5) is blank. What does the orange line mean? Why is it there? Is this something I need to address?

[image: Image of Github file changes with orange line]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's just line highlighting, click on the line number 5 and it will disappear.

Your url should also be ending with #L5. This is mainly for url sharing purposes.

In this case you probably misclicked it yourself.

Comment: I'll admit to being embarrassed to upvote the question and answer (I did) because that's a tacit admission that I wondered the same thing =P

Answer (score 4):

The orange line means that it was highlighted. Check the URL of the Pull Request link you are clicking to see if there is something like #L5 at the end. It is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct, but I must correct riwu because clicking on the line number does not make the highlighting go away. To do that you must physically remove L/R{{lineNumber}} from the URL.

Comment: It's extremely annoying, and still 7 years later, still an eyesore that's difficult to get rid of if you clicked it by mistake.